# Ilnumerics: how to get ILNumerics controls in Windows Form Tools?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, bootcamp, ilnumerics

I am trying to substitute Matlab for good (sorry Mathworks) and use Ilnumerics all the way for my simulations.

I am using it under windows 8, on my MacBook pro 2010, taking advantage of bootcamp 5.0.

My IDE is Visual Studio 2012 and I would like to try to start experimenting with the graphical part of the library.

I was following the quick start guide, but I have a first serious issue.

Under the toolbox I can not locate the ILNumerics group to include ILNumerics controls to be bound to ILnumerics objects. How can I locate those? Do I have to make some changes to my VS to have those?

Another question would be: do I always have to use NuGet Packages manager in order to reference the library? Is there a way to have it locally on my HD and always reference the same copy, instead of importing a copy for any project using ILNumerics?

Thank you very much in advance,

GL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to add ILNumerics controls manually to the Visual Toolbox Window: (from: http://ilnumerics.net/quickstart.html)

"ILNumerics controls are automatically listed in the Toolbox, once ILNumerics is installed into your project. However, in case the ILNumerics controls are not listed in the Toolbox, you can add them manually: Right Click onto the Toolbox, select 'Choose Item'. A dialog opens up and allows you to select the assembly to load controls from. If you have installed ILNumerics via NuGet, the ILNumerics.dll will be found under 'packages/ILNumericsX.X.X/lib' inside your project folder."

Note that it might be a good idea to clear the toolbox from any existing copies of custom controls. In order to reset the toolbox, right click on it and choose: "Reset Toolbox". Afterwards, use the method described above to add ILNumerics Controls to the fresh Toolbox.

Since ILNumerics is a regular .NET library, it could be installed into the GAC instead of using NuGet. Native dependancies would go into the corresponding Windows folders 'System32' and 'SysWOW64' folders. However, we currently do not support the GAC, because NuGet brings so much more convenience in terms of updates and dependency tracking as well as a smooth installation into the project and onto end user machines. What are your concerns regarding NuGet utilization? HD space is cheap nowadays .. ? ;)

Comment: Next to installing ILNumerics in the GAC, one of course can always 'install' the binaries manually into the project(s). However, you will have to pay some attention in order to make it work with AnyCPU targets. See here: http://ilnumerics.net/GetStarted.html (-> Section 2: manual install)

Comment: numbers303, thanks very much. I have tried and it works fine. My bad I did not pay attention to the quick start guide (in fact I was reading from another page of the site).

Comment: Haymo, thanks a lot. I hope I will get proficient ASAP with ilnumerics; congrats for such a fantastic job to you, guys.